# Windows batch script for multiple files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have multiple ascii files like Total-0100.dat and want to batch process using an executable in another directory.

In short,

1. I have multiple files with incremnet of 100 or 1000 e.g. Total-001000.dat, Total-02000.dat up to Total-600000.dat. they are in one drive/drictory say A. say: **A:\work**.
2. I want to batch process these file by using the executable in my program files of C drive. say: **C:\Program Files\Program\run.exe**
3. Finally I store these converted files to another directory. say: **A:\work1** I have an initial code, that is not working. I need help in this regard.

I am working in **Windows 7**...

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1,1,400000) do
"C:\Program Files\Program\run.exe" Total-%%i.dat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add `'('` and `')'` after `do`, write it like this:

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1,1,400000) do (
"C:\Program Files\Program\run.exe" Total-%%i.dat )
```

or on one line without brackets:

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1,1,400000) do "C:\Program Files\Program\run.exe" Total-%%i.dat
```

To run this batch file (which you saved for example in `c:\test\script.bat`) from another directory, simply change your current directory in **cmd** to `A:\work1`, open cmd and type:

```
C:\Windows\system32> a:
A:\> cd work1
A:\work1> c:\test\script.bat
```

or copy the script to `A:\work1\script.bat` and run your script from there:

```
C:\Windows\system32> a:
A:\> cd work1
A:\work1> script.bat
```

An alternative is to open the directory `A:\work1` in Explorer and hold down **SHIFT + right-click** in the right pane in an empty white are and choose `Open command window here` from the menu.

or use the full path in your script:

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1,1,400000) do (
"C:\Program Files\Program\run.exe" A:\work1\Total-%%i.dat )
```

Comment: thanks. It is working. How to set and use different directories as I mention in my question?

Comment: See my updated answer for changing the directory.